# Windows authentication using Kerberos provider is prompting for login details in google chrome but in IE it is not prompting

Tags: asp.net, iis-7.5, kerberos, windows-authentication

Windows authentication is prompting for login details only in chrome browser; IE it is working fine

I have an asp.net application which I have hosted in IIS 7.5 with windows authentication using active directory as the application is internal to my organisation. I am using kerberos provider for authentication. When I am accessing the application using IE it is getting me to the application home page. But when I am trying it through google chrome browser it is prompting me for the login again. If I am providing the same windows AD login details(which I have used to login to my computer) it took me to the application home page. But my question is why it is again prompting for login only in chrome?Is there a way to suppress the additional login prompt? Why the active directory is not able to pass the credentials to chrome browser? Please correct me if I am wrong in any questions or if I missed any settings

Any help here is really appreciated as I am struggling with the issue for some days :) Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you by any chance using Windows 10 and maybe there is a more strict credential isolation in place? Could be that Chrome is not yet using the correct API for that.

Comment: How are you authenticating?

Comment: @DavideVitali I have enabled windows authentication for my website in IIS. All other authentication methods are disabled. And in my providers list Negotiate is on top.I am using specific windows user for the application pool.  What else you want to know

Comment: @eckes You mean Windows 10,as the client machine? How we can fix the API mismatch if in that case?

Comment: @Learner No, sorry... I usually deny anonymous and allow everyone in web.config, then I check the user (as taken from HttpContext.Current.Identity.User.Name) against a SQL db and I’m quite good with it. For *response* on auth process I use filter attribute but that’s MVC, I don’t know if you’re using it. For me it works with every browser

Comment: If this is an API issue Chrome would have to fix it. But I am not sure if this is the case because there are many settings and conditions which have been right to make it work.

Comment: Chrome relies on internet zones (specifically whether the site is considered an intranet site) to determine whether it should automatically and silently send a negotiate (Kerberos|NTLM) ticket. https://superuser.com/questions/61063/can-i-get-chrome-to-work-with-sites-that-use-windows-integrated-security

Comment: @Steve Gone through the link and seems it can be the cause. couldn't try it as it need some network admin privilages to add the url. Will check and update here